# Regular expression for street address

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match street addresses containing the street and number.

I need the expression to match words for the street name, followed by the number.

For example I want to match "somestreet 25", "some other street 23","a-third street 190", but not "a_fourth street 67".

I am trying with it for an hour but I am not even close to good with regex's.

So far all I've got is `/^[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)([\s][0-9]){1,4}$/` but needless to say, it is not working.

--- EDIT ---

I understand that there is no standard, global way of writing the street address, and that regular expressions can't really be complicated enough to cover the problem on a global scope, but the site is for a local restaurant, and all I want is the address to look like it could be an address (even then, without map  and telephone verification it could still be a fake one).

There will, however, be human verification at all times before anything is sent, and also it is a rather small neighborhood, so both the delivery person and the restaurant owner know if the order is fake or not.

All I want is to keep them from getting spammed with silly !@#$ characters in the address, and have a decent readable address formatting for them to work with.

Comment: What makes `a_fourth street 67` not a match?

Comment: @gms8994 the underscore.

Comment: Do you not have streets from countries that put the number first? Or areas which give buildings name but not numbers? Or apartment buildings with letters to identify the part of the building? (221B Baker Street)?

Comment: this will never work in a global context, and probably fail often for a local one.

Comment: In this case it will work because the application is too localized. Far, far from global.

Comment: You basically can't. Street addresses are way too complicated for any sane regex to deal with. Use a third-party solution for this, don't try to reinvent it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work on your examples:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z-]+\s)+\d{1,4}$/
```

Comment: You dont have to add \ if - is the first or last character. Also your pattern will match `- - Road 38` which is not proper.

Comment: Right on both counts! Edited to fix.

Comment: Why's it case sensitive? You could cut down on some code with the `i` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You've overcomplicated it a little bit.  This is a case-insensitive expression that looks for letters with hyphens and spaces, followed by numbers, matching your stated criteria.

```
/^([a-z- ]+)\s+([0-9]+)$/i
```

But what about me? I live on `30th Ave.`

By the way, I used `[0-9]+` for one or more numbers at the end, instead of your `{1,4}` range.  If you must not have more than 4, then switch it back to your range `{1,4}`.

Comment: You don't live in Greece so my client wont really care for you :) .I do, and I thank you for your time though.

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
 /^([A-Z][-A-Z ]+)\s+(\d+)$/i
```

I think street names have no regular formation. So Regular Expression is not applicable for this

Comment: The application is for a restaurant, and the convention on the format of dates is (street name) followed by (number), so regex's are applicable here.